# I need help finding the efficiency of $f(x)= \frac{5x^4}{32} $ using Rejection Sampling (MCMC)

Tags: statistics, sampling

I have $ f(x)= \frac{5x^4}{32}  $ defined on $0<=×<=2$ and I am using rejection sampling with a rectangular bound around the function $[0,2]$ x $[0,2.5]$ since the maximum value is attained at the upper bound at $x=2$. The efficiency should be 1/2.5 ? yet after running my R code where I am simulating from $U~[0,2]$ I get an efficiency of 0.2. ( sorry for any formatting errors, this is my first post)

rejectsim= function(n)
{
t=0
count=0
x=0
while(t
{
count = count + 1  #counts the number of steps
u=runif(1,0,2)
y=runif(1,0,5/2)
f=5/32*u**4
if (y
{
t=t+1
x[t]=u
}
}
print(n/count) #prints the efficiency of the algorithm
x
}

Comment: If the number of points is too small, the actual ratio can differ from the theoretical ratio drastically. How many points did you use ?

Comment: I've used  n =20000 which should be enough, maybe I'm not understanding correctly but if you have a function which integrates to 1 which has a maximum say $K$ then the number of accepted points given we reject any random uniform $U~[0,2]$ observation above $K$  should be $\frac{1}{K}$ ?

Comment: I am not quite understanding the algorithm. You want to calculate the integral with the help of random points and verify whether they are inside the area ?  But then, you would have to check whether $f(x)\ge y$ holds for the particular point.

Comment: Ah, I got it now! The area of the rectangle is $5$ and the area belonging to the integral is $1$ , so the probability that a point is inside the area is $0.2$. So, you got the correct value!

Comment: Ah I see . Thank you Peter